# JQuery hide input box but not input's value

Tags: jquery, input

I have the code:

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="submit" value="Show/Hide Box" id="sub" />
                    <input type="text" id="text" value="Keep Me" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").click(function(){
       $("#text").toggle();
  });
});
```

I want to show & hide the input box everytime the submit button is clicked, but keep the value of the input always shown. I think `replaceWith()` might work but I'm not sure how I can combine what I have now with it. Anyway, if there is a better solution, put it out there.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/byL8L/

Comment: Why would you want to show/hide the input box but not its value? Couldn't you just use the readonly attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the text box value in a span or any other element ans simply toggle their display

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#txt").hide()
     $("#sub").click(function () {
         $("#text").toggle();
         $("#txt").html($("#text").val());
         $('#txt').toggle();
     });
 });
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byL8L/)

Comment: Quick Question : How do I get the text to show without the input box by default.

Comment: Quick answer, put the text in span, and don't hide it by default

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant disabling the text fields on submitting

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click',function (){
   $('input[type=text]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

**Live DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/xy5uh/6/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: The property name is `disabled`, also the second argument should be a boolean value.

Comment: You are welcome. Why did you change the method? For modifying properties `prop` method should be used (_correctly_).

Comment: @undefined: but `.attr()` will also work , check here,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/xy5uh/6/

Answer (score 0):

One of best solutions is to have one div to display text and value input.

```
<div class="display-text"></div>
<div class="input-text"><input type="text" name="message" class="message" /></div>
<input type="submit" name="postme" id="sub" />
```

Then do style:

```
<style>
.display-text { display:none; }
</style>
```

Last step jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").click(function(){ /// onblur of 
        $(".display-text").html($(".message").val()); /// add text to div
        $(".input-text").toggle(); /// hide your input
        $(".display-text").toggle(); /// show text
    });
});
```